# Prevent Q_INVOKABLE to be called from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qobject

I have some Q_INVOKABLE methods of my QObject that I only want to be able to be called from QML, but not from C++. Is there maybe some kind of macro that I can use for this? Maybe a static_assert that will only return true when I'm in moc-generated code?

Comment: I would do some inner object that will be registered to be used in QML.

Comment: Make those methods `private` in C++.  Why would you need to do anything else?

Comment: I also don't want to use them from within the class, so private is not enough